# Top border for bottom navigation bar in android

Tags: android, flutter

After upgrading my flutter from v1 to v2, In the android application, I have a top border in the bottom navigation bar, How can I remove it?

[image]

Comment: can you provide your code ?

Comment: There is no specific code, Just create a fresh flutter application, I think there must be a property in manifest that remove it

Comment: set `elevation` to `0.0`

Comment: Did you try setting the `elevation` to `0.0`.

Comment: `elevation` of what? the bottom navigation bar is not a Dart code, it's created by Android OS, so how can I set `elevation`, is there any service code in dart?